# AWS EKS Returns Error 'certificate has expired or is not yet valid'

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

When I deploy new deployments or edit any settings, It returns following Error

> Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook
> "mpod.elbv2.k8s.aws": Post
> "https://aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc:443/mutate-v1-pod?timeout=10s":
> x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time
> 2022-01-28T02:05:13Z is after 2022-01-20T10:00:30Z

How can i fix it??

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because your time and date are not right. As I can see in the log, your time is 8 days behind the current day.

Please sync your time in this server and try again.

Comment: Today is Jan 28 and his TLS cert expired on Jan 20, what is the problem with server time? I think he just needs to create a new cert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have new certificate for aws-load-balancer-webhook-service. We have issuer set up in the cluster and when we get similar error in OPA we do a rollout restart for opa.